# The "approve" function in near-example/workshop--exploring-assemblyscript-contracts/assembly/A.sample-projects/04.token-contract/

Tags: documentation, smartcontracts, nearprotocol, erc20, assemblyscript

Do anyone mind explaining the `approve` and `allowance` functions in this token [smart contract](https://github.com/near-examples/workshop--exploring-assemblyscript-contracts/blob/master/assembly/A.sample-projects/04.token-contract/assembly/index.ts):

```
export function approve(spender: string, tokens: u64): boolean {
  logging.log("approve: " + spender + " tokens: " + tokens.toString());
  approves.set(context.sender + ":" + spender, tokens);
  return true;
}
```

and

```
export function allowance(tokenOwner: string, spender: string): u64 {
  const key = tokenOwner + ":" + spender;
  if (!approves.contains(key)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return approves.getSome(key);
}
```

I'm trying to make sense of what them are doing against the blog post I read about the ERC-20's `approve` and `allowance` functions from [Cointelegraph](https://cointelegraph.com/explained/erc-20-tokens-explained)

> Not really, because [approve] checks a transaction against the total supply of tokens.
> It makes sure that there are none missing or extra.
> Another way to safeguard the integrity of our hypothetical poker game is to make sure no one brought extra BLU to the table. So, [approve] allows the exchange by checking that the total number of BLU on the table equals 10.

Like I said earlier, it won't hurt to include a little documentation in the token smart contract existing in this [repo](https://github.com/near-examples/workshop--exploring-assemblyscript-contracts). Please!

Answer (score 1):

`Approve` function sets the number of tokens a contract is allowed to transfer from an owner.

`Allowance` grants to a 3rd party permission to use the owner's tokens. That being said, it doesn't mean the ability of someone else to steal your money, but you're allowing smart-contract to use them on your behalf.